# How to get co ordinates of div?

Tags: jquery, css-position

I am using the below code to get the position of dropped elements. I am saving the position to database,so that when the user opens the page next time, the elements are in the same position. It works fine so far, but when the screen size changes the position are changed.for example if i am using big desktop screen ,capture the image position ,save it to database and open the same page in laptop[small screen toughbook] ,the position are varied.

I guess this is bacause the JQuery gets the position of elements relative to page ,not to my container "div ". So how to get position of elements with in a div.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      //Counter
      counter = 0;
      //Make element draggable
      $("#fd img").draggable({
          helper: 'clone',
          containment: '#frame',
          //When first dragged
          stop: function(ev, ui) {

              var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
              objName = "#clonediv" + counter
              $(objName).css({ "left": pos.left, "top": pos.top });
              $(objName).removeClass("drag");
              //When an existiung object is dragged

              var container = $('#frame');
              $(objName).draggable({
                  containment: container,
                  stop: function(ev, ui) {

                      var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
                      //console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                      //console.log(pos.left)
                      //console.log(pos.top)
                  }
              });
          }
      });
      //Make element droppable
      $("#frame").droppable({

          drop: function(ev, ui) {

          var angle; 
              if (document.getElementById('angle').value != "") {
                  angle = document.getElementById('angle').value;
                  document.getElementById('angle').value = 0;
              }
              else {
                  angle = 0;
              }
```

debugger
                  if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1) {

```
                  if (ui.helper.attr('id').indexOf("clonediv") != -1) {
                      var deleteimage = 0;
                      var id = ui.helper.attr('id').substring(8);
                      saveCoords(ui.absolutePosition.left, ui.absolutePosition.top, angle, id, document.getElementById("trafficID").value, deleteimage);

                  }
                  else {
                      var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
                      counter++;
                      var element = $(ui.helper).clone();
                      //var element = element1.resizable();

                      element.addClass("tempclass");
                      $(this).append(element);
                      var deleteimage = 0;
                      element.attr("id", ui.helper.attr('id') + counter);

                      **saveCoords(ui.absolutePosition.left, ui.absolutePosition.top, angle, ui.helper.attr('id') + counter, document.getElementById("trafficID").value, deleteimage);**

                      $(".tempclass").attr("id", "clonediv" + ui.helper.attr('id') + counter);
                      $("#clonediv" + ui.helper.attr('id') + counter).removeClass("tempclass");

                      //$(".tempclass").attr("onclick",function(){ $(this).remove(););
                      //$("#clonediv" + counter).removeClass("tempclass");
                      //Get the dynamically item id

                      draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/);
                      itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1;

                      //console.log(itemDragged)
                      //alert('left' + pos.left + ',top' + pos.top + 'of item' + itemDragged);

                      $("#clonediv" + ui.helper.attr('id') + counter).addClass(itemDragged);
                  }



              }
          }
      });
      //Make the element resizable


  });
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `offset` method gets you the position relative to the document, so you probably want the `position` method instead, that gives you the position relative to the offset parent:

```
var pos = $(ui.helper).position();
```

In your code you are not using the `pos` variable at all, which also is a reason that it doesn't work.

```
saveCoords(pos.left, pos.top, angle, ui.helper.attr('id') + counter);
```

Comment: Both ui.absolutePosition.left and the code suggested results in same left/top values.Pls see my entire code above

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly how your code works, but I think this will do the trick:

```
saveCoords($(ui.helper).offsetLeft, $(ui.helper).offsetTop, angle, ui.helper.attr('id') + counter);
```

Comment: $(ui.helper).offsetLeft gives 'undefined' pls see my entore code above

Comment: offsetLeft is a valid element method ([MDN aritcle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetLeft).)  If it is not working, it must be because ui.helper is null.

Comment: $(ui.helper). is not null ,only $(ui.helper).offsetLeft  is 'undefined' ,i didn't see any syntax for this .

Comment: Add this in there... what does it say? `alert("L: " + $(ui.helper).offsetLeft + "     T:" + $(ui.helper).offsetTop);`